# Increase in gain of CP micro-strip patch antenna

Tags: rf, antenna, radiation

I have successfully designed my circularly polarized patch antenna shown below. I used the slot method. Which as a bandwidth of 23MHz and a resonance frequency of 915MHz. Though the bandwidth is small it is more than sufficient for my application. The axial ratio achieved was 1.7dB at 90 degrees. However, the gain is rather disappointing at -1.5 dBi. Does anyone know of methods I can use to improve my gain?

[image]

Comment: When it comes to antennas there is always a duality / tention between directionality and gain... also remember to dimension your dB's properly (e.g. dBi deciBels relative to an isotropic antenna)

Comment: If you have additional information related to your original question, use the "edit" button to add the information there. It was put "on hold" in order to allow you to improve it before people try to answer it. Do not create a duplicate question.

Comment: @DaveTweed please remove this hold as this question has nothing do with the previous edits. I don't get why questions are put on hold and make the user wait. The user will only know what info needs to be added when other users give their input. I cannot read the users' minds. This is probably the second time you have intervened when I stated the difference if there was any. Please refrain from this. By you hinting its a duplicate will confuse users even further. Since this question contradicts the previous question and users will think all my questions are just duplicates.

Comment: Can someone assist in removing this hold? My question is not related to the previous question as one can see from the picture. The previous question uses a quarter wavelength design which did not work while this question uses a slot design. So I cannot understand why it is a duplicate! This is completely unacceptable! This moderator is giving users a false impression and hence not allowing me to use this platform for its intended purpose.

Comment: @DaveTweed did you also put the "Axial ratio of a square microstrip antenna" question on hold? If so what was the reason?

Comment: You have asked a long series of vague questions about the design of patch antennas that have not received a lot of response from other users. The nature of the questions suggests that you found some nifty modeling software, but that you really don't know much about the theory associated with such antennas. The Q&A format of this site is not suitable for giving you that kind of training -- indeed, entire books and college courses have been devoted to the topic. At this point, you should either stick to "cookbook" antenna designs, or invest the time to get up to speed on the theory.

Comment: @DaveTweed I am at a point of optimization which no textbook or courses will tell you what method to use. It comes with experience which this platform as an abundance of and what I required. I will keep getting no responses if you continuously mark my questions as duplicates. I also take it you did not read the text, as it clearly states a slot antenna design as the previous question was a different type of design and hence not a duplicate. There exist many different patch antenna designs. Please justify why this is a duplicate question? Citing which parts are duplicates

Comment: @DaveTweed if you cannot justify why this a duplicate, please remove the hold. Thank you

Comment: @DaveTweed since you have not provided a justification for exactly why this question is a duplicate of the previous question. I take it you think since you have "authority" this makes you a being of a higher power and we are all beneath you. This shows me what type of person and character you have. On that note, I find your behavior targeted with no justification or your motives behind it. Since I will not get any responses again since you marked it as duplicate again and FYI why are my questions vague when I got a vote up, on the previous question...

Comment: Yes, I do have some authority here -- note the diamond after my name. It is my job to make sure that the standards of the site are upheld and to try to optimize the experience of the majority of site users. You, on the other hand, have told us nothing about your level of training or experience (not here and not in [your profile](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/159693/joey?tab=profile)), and as I said before, the language of your questions strongly suggests that you don't have a lot of skill in this particular area.

Comment: You have also never told us anything about your actual application, nor which aspects of the antenna performance are most important to it (and why). This is probably why your questions have not received a lot of response from site users. The upvote doesn't really mean much -- there has been at least one person on the site upvoting low-quality questions and answers for the past several months.

Comment: @DaveTweed this is the third time I'm asking this simple question. Why is this a duplicate question when it's not the same antenna design as the previous question. Hopefully this time I will get an answer...

Comment: [You have asked](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/159693/joey?tab=questions) a total of 27 questions (starting on April 4 of this year) on this topic of a 915 MHz RFID system that you seem to be trying to design, many of which have received no upvotes and no answers. None of this seems to be helping you, and it certainly isn't adding any value to the site for other visitors. I agree that the specific details of this question are different from the other, but the pattern about optimizing some aspect of an antenna design is identical. They might as well be combined into one question.

Comment: @DaveTweed thank you. Due to antenna theory being so complex that even the smallest of details in terms of optimization as its own entire "book" I felt the need to separate my questions. As I thought it would have confused the users. From your reply I now see that my approach regarding getting help was wrong. I don't think posting a new question that encompasses all the questions will help much any more.I feel that I should rather resign any efforts in posting a new question as this will cause even more confusion.I therefore like to thank you and the users for thier assistance thus far.